# Xcode 8.x hangs too much in the XIB files

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, xib

I am using Xcode 8.1,
Storyboard files are working well but whenever I open the XIB files, Xcode sucks and started hanging.
Please let me know, what is the issue with this buggy Xcode.

Or should I look for any other alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a 3.4 GHz Intel Core i7 with 32 GB 1600 MHz DDR3, 2 GB GTX 680MX and Xcode will hang.  I'll admit that I don't always see a difference between editing a .xib and .storyboard but Interface Builder seems to be a "bad citizen" when it comes to resources in general.  As a result I have changed my work flow a little to avoid those moments of frustration and get work done.

**1. Avoid IBDesignable if possible.**

If they do actually work/load properly they are at best just showing you what you could see by simply running your app.  If I'm prototyping a custom control/view I will use a playground with PlaygroundSupport and a liveView.  Note that I'm not saying IBInspectable is bad.  I use it all the time.

**2. Use Xcode's "Editor > Refactor to Storyboard" as an alternative to xibs and large storyboards.**

One thing that seems to help me is to use small storyboards in a way thats like using xibs.  Although it is possible, I'm don't strictly mean one storyboard for every view controller. More along the lines of one storyboard per *process* in your application.  For example, I usually give a signup process its own *signup.storyboard* that only contains scenes relevant to signup.  This has the advantage of bundling multiple scenes and preserving the ability to use segues while, being just as flexible as xibs, enabling you to switch between UI versions by simply changing which storyboard file you load.

**Code Example**

For example, in initial view controller of a signup process storyboard I will create the following:

```
public class func instantiateFromStoryboard() -> SignupViewController {
    let storyboardName = "Signup"
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
    let storyboardIdentifier = "SignupViewController"
    let signupVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyboardIdentifier) as! SignupViewController

    return signupVC
}
```

***Update:*** I have created a simple UIViewController extension that is essentially the generic version of the code above.  See the readme for details.  https://github.com/kyleishie/InitFromStoryboard

**Storyboard Only Example**

This can be accomplished, without code, with only storyboards as well by using cross storyboard segues.  In the object library while editing your storyboard there is an object called *Storyboard Reference*.  Drag one out and set its *Storyboard* property to the destination storyboard.  You can now create segues to the destination in the way that you would expect.  If desired you can specific a specific scene to by entering its *storyboardIdentifier* as the *Referenced ID*.  By default it uses the storyboard's initialViewController.

Using this method, or something similar, you can easily swap out the entire signup process UI by

• Creating a new storyboard with the appropriate scenes.

• Assigning the existing classes to the new scenes and wire up all of the outlets and actions.

• Change the *storyboardName* above in the initialViewController or *storyboard* property in the storyboard reference object that segues to this process.

[Ray Weinerlich has a good tutorial on using storyboards with iOS9+.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/115697/ios-9-storyboards-tutorial-whats-new-in-storyboards)

I realize that this workflow may not be exactly what you are asking but  it may help with your particular issue if storyboards are working well but xibs aren't. ;)

Comment: Understood. But can I navigate from one storyboard's viewcontroller to another storyboard using **segue**? Do I have to embed navigationcontroller in every storyboard or a single navigationcontroller in the starting storyboard is enough?

Comment: @Poles see my edit.  I added a storyboard only example as well as a link to a good storyboard tutorial.   As far as using a navigation controller you should certainly have one initial navigation controller but I find myself having multiple in every app that I build.  The "signup process" above would have its own modally present navigation controller but thats more dependent on the app itself and not storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using low configuration mac machine then definitely it will hang. If you are looking for alternative then you should look for [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/) but you need to know C#.

Comment: Configuration is
2.6 GHz Intel Core i5,
8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3,
Intel Iris 1536 MB,

Is this configuration low?

Comment: Yes for Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: You need at least 3.5 GHz Core i5 processor.

Comment: ok thanks, but will it affect performance?
Or any other suggestion which could work with current configuration, It would be appreciatable.

Comment: Please let me know what is the configuration of your system?

Comment: And it is working fine in Storyboard, it actually hang too much in the XIB files.

Comment: While working with Xcode keep only those apps opened which are really important at that time. Use any RAM & System cache cleaner like CleanMyMac. Periodically clean Xcode's DerivedData.

Comment: If your XIB contains too many views, imageview, button, etc then the Xcode will hang.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132705/discussion-between-poles-and-gopal-devra).

Comment: Using a different language and IDE is not a valid workaround.

Comment: i7 quad core, 16GB, SSD, brand new High Sierra and Xcode installed from a week: same results, hangs, stops, crashes.